# Phonegap + Eclipse + Cordova -- No config.xml

Tags: android, cordova

I just created an Android Project in Eclipse with all the phonegap and cordova files as expected. However, I have no such directory, and thus, no config.xml. According to the Apache Cordova documentation, it is supposed to be located at: app/res/xml/config.xml.

My folder structure is as follows, for the /res directory:

```
/res/drawable-hdpi
/res/drawable-ldpi
/res/drawable-mdpi
/res/drawable-mdpi
/res/layout
- /res/layout/main.xml
/res/values
- /res/layout/strings.xml
```

What have I done wrong or what step am I missing? I hope I have provided enough information.

Comment: How did you create the project?

Answer (score 2):

Just create the /res/xml/ folder manually. Then create config.xml using a text editor and use this as a template: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/blob/master/lib/android/xml/config.xml

Comment: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/blob/master/lib/android/example/res/xml/config.xml

Comment: Thanks! What I cant understand is why there are no template files created automatically...

Answer (score 2):

Whenever we create a cordova project, `config.xml` gets created automatically. We need to check if there is any folder in excluded list.

Go to `Build path` -> `Resources` -> Check for excluded resources.

Remove them from the project and build the project. You will be able to view the `config.xml` and `www` folder in the `Project/Package Explorer`.