# Add a .js to a Cordova project crashes the build process

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Running Cordova CLI 6.0.0 with Android platform 5.1.1

Creating, adding Android, building and running the sample project works out of the box.

But I now want to add one .js program. If I add it in the obvious place (www / js) or even in www, the build fails with what looks like a spurious error (see below**).

If I load the project into Eclipse (Mars), the build apparently works but running the app fails with ‘res/xml/config.xml is missing’, ‘unable to open asset URL: file///android_asset/www/js/’ and unable to open asset URL: file///android_asset/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/whitelist.js’
In other words adding the .js file upsets Eclipse’s ability to find other files nearby in the tree.

**DAK please how I simply add a .js file to the default project?**

**
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'
com.android.ide.common.process.
ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.E
xecException: Process 'command 'C:\Eclipse\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sd
k\build-tools\21.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1073741819

If I issue a “gradlew.bat --info build clean” command, I get:
Script 'C:\ \platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 117
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.  Unable to determine Android SDK directory

Comment: The reason for gradle build failure could be that the ANDROID_HOME system environment variable is not set properly. Check out this link for eclipse errors - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649930/phonegap-eclipse-cordova-no-config-xml Could be something to do with excluded resources configuration

Comment: I build with cordova and log show me ANDROID_HOME & JAVA_HOME :
`ANDROID_HOME=/Users/userMe/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: @user1269586 Could you share the project for testing here? If you are using cordova CLI, were you able to add android platform without any error?

Comment: @user1269586 If there is no update on this, why have bounty?

Answer (score 2):

Try to set `sdk.dir=/Users/userMe/Library/Android/sdk` in **local.properties** file on the root folder of your project.